# Where can I discuss?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I'm programming in C++, and I was looking for "the best" compilers (size, features...), but I read "How to Ask", and I didn't post the question. If I need to dicuss (important things, like this), get opinions from the users, what's the best place to? Is there any programming-discussion affiliated site?

Comment: "the best" doesn't exist. Not without qualifying what you are optimizing for (in this case - executable size? features - what features are important to you?). You **can** ask "What is a good c++ compiler with feature set X and results Y. I have tried compilers Z and Q with these results, and here is why they are lacking.". See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for a blog post discussing this kind of question.

Comment: You may have better luck at Quora. Samples: *[What is the best compiler for developing C/C++ applications on Windows?](https://www.quora.com/Compilers/What-is-the-best-compiler-for-developing-C-C++-applications-on-Windows)*, *[What is a good, friendly and free C++ compiler?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-friendly-and-free-C++-compiler)*, and *[What C++ compiler is the best for a beginner to use?](https://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/What-C++-compiler-is-the-best-for-a-beginner-to-use)*.

Comment: Hey, hey @PeterMortensen, a begginer?!? :P

Comment: @Lucas Henrique: that was just for illustration purposes.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Just kidding.

Comment: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192468/165773) says Slant _is best_ for stuff like that: _'If you just want to make a quick decision on a "What is the best...?" style question, [Slant](http://www.slant.co/) was built with exactly that sort of thing in mind.'_

Comment: `+1` for _Slant_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###You cannot discuss here

Well you're right you cannot discuss that here since discussion and opinion based questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow and it is written in their How To Ask page.

###You might get the answer at their website

You're creating an application using C++ and my guess would be to use Visual Studio, but you can get that type of help from Official C++ website too.

http://isocpp.org/ Mat corrected me in this; this one is the official site

http://www.cplusplus.com (other site)

###My Suggestion:

You can try out Visual Studio from Microsoft. That includes a compiler for you, to compile the softwares written in C++. But you might go there; on their website!

###Discussion; ummm chat?

Secondly, you can **discuss** some stuff at the chat rooms in Stack Overflow. They are generally meant to person-to-person discussion or person-to-community discussion. But still note that they are not for questioning. You cannot ask for opinions there.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com

You can look for Lounge<C++> chat room, but I am not sure whether that covers your topic or not.

###[Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) might be the place

Last thing, you can go to http://programmers.stackexchange.com I think your question would fit there and not on Stack Overflow. But still no site on Stack Exchange is perfect for discussion since this network is a Question and Answer site. You can try out a forum!

Comment: cplusplus.com is not an official website. http://isocpp.org/ is. And no, that sort of question _does not_ belong on Programmers.

Comment: That what I needed! I'll try Chat, then Programmers. About your suggestion: I need an cross-platform compiler, lightweight, have support for threads and expensive optimizations (like MinGW -O3, max optmization). I really think that I'll have to searche some hours ;).

Comment: @Mat .. thanks sir :) I never knew that one..

Comment: @LucasHenrique good! :) Microsoft's compiler; hehe you knw would work with Windows only. You can try out a simple Open Source compiler then :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan, the [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com) is not Official, but is also a good site, it handle almost everything of C++. I recommend to edit and add the site to the answer (for the other users).

Comment: @LucasHenrique included it..:)